# How to QJackCtl with ASIO and virtual audio devices

Tags: windows, audio-route

Setup:

- Windows 10 Pro x64 20H2
- Sound Interface `Behringer U-Phoria UMC-22` (using with ASIO4ALL)
- Headphones `Logitech G533` (through ASIO4ALL as well)

I need to be able to manage my audio inputs/outputs so i could playback my guitar but also could let that sound to discord and other applications.

In general i looking for a way to replace `VB-Audio VoiceMeeter`, it could work with ASIO and WDM at the same time

[QJackCtl Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJnPY.png)

[ASIO4ALL Devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpHjT.png)

I tried to do it with `ASIOLinkPro` connected to JACK asio, but it has too few input/output channels (only four)

[QJackCtl Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNT5W.png)